# Can i save Concrete 5 backend content like my footer and use it again, without using CSS or HTML code?

Tags: concrete5

Can i save Concrete5 backend content like my footer and use it again, without using CSS or HTML code, just in the Concrete5 backend? 
So that the guy who have to work in the Backend later, don´t  have to put the content in manually in the content boxes?
*(sry, my english is not so good)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stacks or global areas, if that's what you mean? (Global areas are technically stacks, but I digress).

You can find stacks in the back end in the dashboard by typing "stacks" in the intelligent search. You can basically "save" groups of blocks in a stack for later use. If you're using 5.7, you can place stacks by opening the add block pane, then clicking "blocks" and choosing "stacks".

If you define a global area in the theme, the content will show up on every page they references that global area. But that's probably not what you want.

Comment: Thank you, i guess this will help me ;)